# How to host a virtural private server?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vps

How can I host several VPS's on my Ubuntu computer? I have all ports open, and want to host several virtual private servers for a few people. They need to be able to connect to a VPS on my computer through SSH. How can I do this? I tried proxmox and Didn't have much success. I would like to run Ubuntu 64Bit on all the Servers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need a [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) to run each guest OS. The hypervisor is in charge of managing the other virtual machines (VPSs) it is running.

[KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) is the natural opensource choice for Ubuntu.

You can read how to [install KVM here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/kvm-on-ubuntu-14.04/)

But the following command will get you everything you need:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

I would also suggest you look at [virt-manager](https://virt-manager.org/) which will help you manage your vm's in a nice graphical interface.

you can install it with `sudo apt-get install virt-manager`

Good luck!

Comment: Isn't that just for Virtual machines? I am wanting to run a VPS so others outside my network on a different computer can connect to there own server.  Such as Openvz but Openvz never works for some reason. @stemartin

Comment: @C.c.h A VPS is just server that is running in a virtual machine, install a server operating system in the VM.

Comment: Right, But I am trying to setup a VPS like you can buy from a  host, but home host it myself that way I can give someone on a different computer a IP Address, username and password to connect. @stemartin

Comment: Yes you can do all that with KVM a router and a block of IP from your ISP.

Comment: Seem to have got it working, But how can I set a username and password for others to connect outside my network with KVM? Thank you. @stemartin

Comment: Install a vm setup a user, setup the networking. Give other person the details.

Comment: I installed a VM on KVM, cant figure out how to setup a User? I couldn't find anything on google about setting up a user and pass for one. @stemartin

Comment: A VPS, VM is nothing special its just an OS. Dont search for how to setup a user on a VPS, just how to setup a user on <the os you are using>